# Tomcat stopping a thread to avoid potential memory leaks

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Every time I start debugging my WebApp (Netbeans 7.0 + spring 3 + jsp) the debugger breaks a couple of times in ThreadPoolExecutor.java after Tomcat raises this exception:

"Stopping thread http-bio-8080-exec-3 to avoid potential memory leaks after a context was stopped."

[image: screenshot showing ThreadPoolExecutor.java]

I am unable to identify why this is happening. Is it due to a problem in my code? If so, how can I locate the problem? If this is "normal", then how can I prevent the IDE from bothering me with it every time?

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the exact error only in Eclipse running Spring MVC. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this. However, I discovered how to ignore the issue by unchecking the "Stop on uncaught exceptions" option in Tools|Miscellaneous|Java Debugger|General (Netbeans). Now Netbeans never bothers me about it. Interesting that you are using Spring too. Are you using any Listeners?

Comment: Not yet. It's Ext-JS front backed by Spring MVC in very early stages

Comment: Also seeing this problem with plain Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819.   While running:  Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Server built:   Oct 18 2013 01:07:38
Server number:  7.0.47.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     10.9
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_45-b18
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Comment: Just for the record, I eventually discovered a resource leak (a database connection) which I plugged and the above exception no longer occurs. So the bug was in my code and not in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be part of [Bug 49159 - Improve ThreadLocal memory leak clean-up](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49159) that was fixed in 7.0.6, but it is part of the [MemoryLeakProtection](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) mechanism in Tomcat 7+

There is another answer posted here [Is this very likely to create a memory leak in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292456/160361) that explains this in further detail.

As you already noted in your comments, you can disable the debugger in NetBeans using **Tools|Miscellaneous|Java|Java Debugger|General (Netbeans)** , and de-selecting the **stop on uncaught exceptions** checkbox.

Comment: Just FYI, Bug 49159 was marked resolved with Tomcat 7.0.6 yet I get this problem running: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Server built:   Oct 18 2013 01:07:38
Server number:  7.0.47.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     10.9
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_45-b18
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation.   But only in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819.